# Dynamically generated Button click not getting called?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have associated a Button ID while generating Buttons dynamically and created a Button event handler as follows:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

Button Click event:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b = (Button)sender;
    string i = b.ID.Substring(b.ID.Length - 1, 1);
    int j1 =Convert.ToInt32(i);
    id1 = to[j1];
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Type.GetType("System.String"), 
        "addScript", "PassValues('" + id1 + "')", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
       "sendMessage", "javascript:sendMessage(); ", true);
}
```

However this event is not getting called i have placed all my controls inside an UpdatePanel

EDIT: What is happening is on button click somehow a function is getting called which is present on `Page.Load`

```
protected void getEntriesRight()
{
    j = (int)Session["j"];

    int n1 = j + 3;

    for (; j <= n1; j++)
    {
        if (j < fr.data.Length)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl listItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl a1 = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            Label anchor = new Label();
            Image im = new Image();

            btn = new Button();
            im.ImageUrl = fr.data[j].pic_square;
            im.Height = 45;
            im.Width = 47;


            btn.CssClass = "btn-add";
            btn.Text = "Invite";
            to[j] = fr.data[j].uid;

            btn.ID = "btn" + j;


            a1.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            anchor.Text = fr.data[j].name;
            a1.Controls.Add(btn);
            a1.Controls.Add(im);
            a1.Controls.Add(anchor);
            listItem.Controls.Add(a1); 
            list.Controls.Add(listItem);

                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        }
    }

    Session["j"] = j;
}
```

Help!

Comment: We need to see how you're creating `btn`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dynamically generated controls have to be recreated on every postback in order for their events to fire.  This is one of the most commonly-encountered problems with generating controls programmatically in .NET, and it is discouraged if you can find a way around it.

For example, if you have a button that should only be present when another button is clicked, have the button in the page to begin with, and use the `Visible` property to control whether it is shown or not.

---

Regarding your edit. Every post-back to the server, even inside an `UpdatePanel`, is going to call `Page_Load`.  If you want to detect whether a request has come from an `UpdatePanel` then you need to check `!Page.IsAsync` before calling the function.

Comment: Well thats not exactly what my problem is what is happening now is another function rather than  this method is being called i don't know why :/